# Small files available in ADLS Gen2 location even after delta optimization

Tags: scala, optimization, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am having a comparatively big external delta table which have data on ADLS gen2 location.
This table is partitioned by **id** and **signal_date**

I am running a delta optimize query on this table on weekly basis. The query is as shown below.

[image]

For few partitions we could see optimization runs more than 2 hrs as highlighted above.

And for the entire partitions for a week, this job is running more than 48 hrs and have to kill it in between in order to proceed with data load into this table. (otherwise encounter with concurrent operation failure error on the partition)

Even after this optimization I could see many small files in the ADLS location for that partition as shown below.

[image]
[image]

Is there anything wrong happening during the optimization considering the huge time for execution and availability of small files after optimization?

Any thoughts/points appreciated!

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTIMIZE doesn't remove the small files after it's finished - it creates a new version that refers new, bigger files, and marks old small files as removed, but the actual removal will happen when you run [VACUUM](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#remove-files-no-longer-referenced-by-a-delta-table).

Here an example of the transaction log for OPTIMIZE performed:

```
{"add":{"path":"part-00000-5046c283-8633-4fe2-8c99-ada26908e2d0-c000.snappy.parquet",
  "partitionValues":{},"size":1105,"modificationTime":1650281913487,
  "dataChange":false,"stats":"{\"numRecords\":200,\"minValues\":{\"id\":0},\"maxValues\":{\"id\":99},\"nullCount\":{\"id\":0}}"}}
{"remove":{"path":"part-00002-57c4253a-5bdc-4d3e-9886-601fa793cdf6-c000.snappy.parquet",
  "deletionTimestamp":1650281912032,"dataChange":false,
  "extendedFileMetadata":true,"partitionValues":{},"size":536}}
...other remove entries...
{"commitInfo":{"timestamp":1650281913514,"operation":"OPTIMIZE",
  "operationParameters":{"predicate":"[\"true\"]"},"readVersion":1,
  "isolationLevel":"SnapshotIsolation","isBlindAppend":false,
  "operationMetrics":{"numRemovedFiles":"16","numRemovedBytes":"8640","p25FileSize":"1105","minFileSize":"1105","numAddedFiles":"1","maxFileSize":"1105","p75FileSize":"1105","p50FileSize":"1105","numAddedBytes":"1105"},
  "engineInfo":"Apache-Spark/3.2.1 Delta-Lake/1.2.0",
  "txnId":"31a68055-7932-4266-8290-9939af7e6a84"}}
```

Comment: Thank You Alex. On that note I have few doubts to get clarified.
    
1. `Do we need to run manually VACCUM command to get rid of these small files?`  

2. `Is the default retention period is 30 days ?`  

3. `These small files even after optimization will be removed after retention period ?`

Comment: Yes, vacuum needs to be executed regularly. All files marked as removed will be removed by vacuum. Default retention is 7 days.